# how to retrieve object value from mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The object look like this :

```
 {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5969b38a9ab0c60370a6dea3"),
            "name" : "789",
            "dec" : "789",
            "regular" : "789",
            "sale" : "78",
            "stock" : "8",
            "cat" : {
                    "wallets" : [{
                                    "selected" : "true",
                                    "subcategory" : "leather"
                            }]
            },
            "imgs" : [
                    "file-1500099465305.png",
                    "file-1500099465310.png"
            ],
            "__v" : 0
    }
```

my question is

> how to retrieve a particular value in mongodb via query?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> import your model and find your instance via query:

```
    export function myFunc(req, res) {
          return Model.find({ 'name.last': 'Ghost' }}  //your condition
            })
            .then(entity=> {
              if (entity) {
                console.log(entity)                   // to see object
                res.status(200).json({'entity': entity}).end();
              } else {
                return res.status(404).end();  
              }
            }).catch(handleError(res));             // error handling
        }
```

now when you call this function you will get entity as object and you can get entity object keys from it.